# Filtering by QueryString doesn't work in SPD 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, external-list, query-string

I have an external list, I have setup and use querystring to filter list in **SharePoint Designer 2013** like this posted:

http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/

But nothing happen after filtering?

Perhaps I miss something in **SharePoint 2013**

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Updated the information: when I do follow the link:

http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/

then I convert my SP2013 external listview webpart into **Server Render** the filter work fine, so why?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. After convert the webpart to "Server Render", the filter works well. However, the interface of external list is witched to SP 2010, not 2013. Any solutions?